# How to get log4net csv logging to create only one header

Tags: csv, log4net

I working with the log4net csv logging. Works fine except everytime it logs, it recreates the header. Anyway to just get it to append a row without the header? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set append on false, than you will create a new file every time with only one header.

Comment: What I'm looking for is one file, mutliple rows or log records.